# DELETE using PreCopy Script in CopData activity

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, etl, azure-data-factory

I have simple copy data activity with source and destination as a table in Azure Data Factory, Before inserting I'm having delete script in the pre-copy script option. The Delete should be done on the basis of parameters passed to the pipeline.
I tried this way but getting error.

DELETE FROM [dbo].[StgMetricLoad] where TransactionKey in(pipeline().parameters.TransactionKey)

Comment: hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Hi ,I didn't tried ...having lot of work ....will try ASAP

Comment: Sure Sure take your time.

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience,you can't merge pipeline string parameter into sql string like that directly. This should be configured as dynamic content with [@cancat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions) built-in function.

I tested it in the Set Variable Activity:

```
@concat('DELETE FROM [dbo].[StgMetricLoad] where TransactionKey in(',
pipeline().parameters.keystring,
')')
```

[image]

Test Output:

[image]

Comment: How can i pass the Set variable to Copydata activity?

Comment: @VeeramallaSandeep if you already set value to variable , you could refer the variable in  copy activity. `@variable("Column")`

Comment: @VeeramallaSandeep If you still has issue,please post more details in your question for clarification.